# No transaction is currently active error with eclipselink-2.5.2 Spring 4.1.1

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, eclipselink

**SOLVED** : Go through comments/chat

I am using Spring 4.1.1 with annotation based configuration. While trying to use eclipselink with spring, i get error on `merge` method stating `No transaction is currently active`

Following is the **stacktrace:**

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.throwCheckTransactionFailedException(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.checkForTransaction(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:50)
Exception occured at : javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.checkForTransaction(EntityManagerImpl.java:2041)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:863)
    at com.cdl.box.dao.GenericDao.merge(GenericDao.java:61)
    at com.cdl.box.dao.GenericDao$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9e11ea6a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.cdl.box.dao.PersonDao$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$51ee0a8f.merge(<generated>)
    at com.cdl.box.service.person.PersonService.addPerson(PersonService.java:23)
    at com.cdl.box.service.person.PersonService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$dbc06f33.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:266)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.cdl.box.service.person.PersonService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$35eaf713.addPerson(<generated>)
    at com.cdl.box.controller.PersonController.add(PersonController.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:781)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:721)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:877)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**WebConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.myapp")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        System.out.println("UrlBasedViewResolver........");
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        MultipartResolver resolver = new StandardServletMultipartResolver();
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("In Resouce Handler");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/defaultTheme/");
    }


}
```

DBConfig.java

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DatabasePlatform;
import org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableLoadTimeWeaving;
import org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.instrument.classloading.SimpleLoadTimeWeaver;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaDialect;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class DBConfig {

    @Value("${jdbc.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;

    @Value("${jdbc.url}")
    private String url;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${eclipselink.persistenceUnitName}")
    private String persistenceUnitName;

    @Bean()
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        BoneCPDataSource ds = new BoneCPDataSource();
        System.out.println("Driver Name : " + driverClassName);
        System.out.println("Url : " + url);
        ds.setDriverClass(driverClassName);
        ds.setJdbcUrl(url);
        ds.setUsername(username);
        ds.setPassword(password);
        ds.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(5);
        ds.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(2);
        ds.setAcquireIncrement(2);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(getDataSource());          
        em.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect());
        em.setPackagesToScan("com.myapp.model", "com.myapp.model.person");
        em.setPersistenceUnitName(persistenceUnitName);
        DatabasePlatform dp = new MySQLPlatform();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(getEclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter());
        //em.setLoadTimeWeaver(new SimpleLoadTimeWeaver());
        em.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter getEclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter() {
        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.MySQLPlatform");
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        return vendorAdapter;
    }


    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactoryBean().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaDialect jpaDialect() {
        return new EclipseLinkJpaDialect();
    }
}
```

**WebInitializer.java**

```
import javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class WebInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("In WebApplicationInitializer.....");
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

         // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        servletContext.setInitParameter("contextConfigLocation", "<NONE>");


        rootContext.register(DBConfig.class);
        rootContext.register(WebConfig.class);      

        rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);                      

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
        servlet.setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement("/img", 1024*1024*5, 1024*1024*5*5, 1024*1024));  

    }

}
```

Fetching the data works perfectly. Error occurs during insert/update using eclipselink.

I went through lot of posts & applied all suggestions. But unfortunately it is not working. I am not sure what I am missing. Do you see anything wrong with the configuration ? Please suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

**EDIT:**

Following is my service class with @Transactional.

```
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.myapp.dao.PersonDao;
import com.myapp.model.person.Person;


@Service
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class PersonService {

    @Autowired
    private PersonDao personDao;

    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        Person p = personDao.merge(person);     
        System.out.println(p.getCity());
    }

    public void updatePerson(Person person) {
        personDao.persist(person);      
    }

    public Person getPerson(int id) {
        return personDao.findById(id);      
    }

    public void deletePerson(int id) {
        personDao.deleteById(id);       
    }

    public List<Person> getPersons(int first, int rows){
        ReadAllQuery readAllQuery = new ReadAllQuery(Person.class);
        readAllQuery.setJPQLString("SELECT OBJECT(per) FROM Person per");
        return personDao.executeReadAllQuery(readAllQuery, first, rows);
    }
}
```

With @Transactional on service class I get following error while I start `Tomcat`

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personController' defined in file [D:\Hemraj-Dev\apache-tomcat-7.0.56\webapps\yourbox\WEB-INF\classes\com\myapp\controller\PersonController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.myapp.service.person.PersonService]: : Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.dao.PersonDao com.myapp.service.person.PersonService.personDao; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.myapp.dao.PersonDao field com.myapp.service.person.PersonService.personDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.dao.PersonDao com.myapp.service.person.PersonService.personDao; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.myapp.dao.PersonDao field com.myapp.service.person.PersonService.personDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:751)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1133)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1036)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.dao.PersonDao com.myapp.service.person.PersonService.personDao; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.myapp.dao.PersonDao field com.myapp.service.person.PersonService.personDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:743)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.myapp.dao.PersonDao com.myapp.service.person.PersonService.personDao; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.myapp.dao.PersonDao field com.myapp.service.person.PersonService.personDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.myapp.dao.PersonDao field com.myapp.service.person.PersonService.personDao to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy25
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:164)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:168)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:741)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:551)
    ... 38 more
```

**EDIT2:**

I have replaced new stacktarce on top of question for `No Transaction is currently active` error. Following is my DAOs.

**PersonDao.java:**

```
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.myapp.model.person.Person;

@Repository("personDao")
public class PersonDao extends GenericDao<Person, Integer> {

    @Override
    public int deleteById(Integer id) {
        Query q = getEntityManager().createQuery(
                "delete from Employees where employeeId = :id");
        q.setParameter("id", id);
        return q.executeUpdate();       
    }

}
```

**GenericDao.java**

```
  public class GenericDao<E, ID extends Serializable>{

    private final Class<E> persistentClass;
    protected EntityManager entityManager;
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "cdlbox")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Value("${eclipselink.persistenceUnitName}")
    private String persistenceUnitName;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public GenericDao() {
        this.persistentClass = (Class<E>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    protected Class<E> getEntityClass() {
        return persistentClass;
    }

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        return em;
    }

    public E merge(E entity) {
        E e = null;
        try{
            e = em.merge(entity);
            em.flush();
        }catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured at : " + ex);
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
        return e;
    }

    public void persist(E entity) {
        em.persist(entity);     
    }

    public void remove(E entity) {
        em.remove(entity);      
    }

    public E findById(ID id) {
        return em.find(getEntityClass(), id);       
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
    public List<E> executeNamedQuery(String queryName,
            Map<String, Object> parameterMap) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(
                queryName);
        if (parameterMap != null) {
            for (String param : parameterMap.keySet()) {
                query.setParameter(param, parameterMap.get(param));
            }
        }
        return query.getResultList();       
    }

    public List<E> executeNamedQuery(String queryName) {
        return executeNamedQuery(queryName, null);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
    public int getCount(String countField, Expression expr) {
        ReportQuery query = new ReportQuery(getEntityClass(), null);
        query.setSelectionCriteria(expr);
        query.addCount("count", query.getExpressionBuilder().get(countField)
                .distinct());

        List<ReportQueryResult> result = (List<ReportQueryResult>) getSession().executeQuery(query);
        ReportQueryResult reportQueryResult = result.get(0);
        BigDecimal count = (BigDecimal) reportQueryResult.getResults().get(0);
        return count.intValueExact();
    }

    protected Session getSession() {
        //EntityManagerImpl has to be imported as org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl
        Session session = ((EntityManagerImpl) em).getActiveSession();
        return session;
    }

    public List<E> executeReadAllQuery(ReadAllQuery readAllQuery, int first,
            int rows) {
        readAllQuery.setFirstResult(first);
        readAllQuery.setMaxRows(first + rows);

        return executeDatabaseQuery(readAllQuery);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
    public List<E> executeDatabaseQuery(DatabaseQuery q) {
        List<E> resultList = (List<E>) getSession().executeQuery(q);
        return resultList;
    }

    public int deleteById(ID id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }


}
```

**EDIT3:**

Got [this](http://pastebin.com/ui7eFjWa) exception while using `@PersistenceContext`

Comment: There is nothing regarding transactions in your stacktrace, so they aren't enabled. Make sure you have `@Transactional` on your services.

Comment: @M.Deinum - When I use `@Transactional` with service class I get exception while starting tomcat. Please see my EDIT section.

Comment: My guess your `PersonDao` implements interfaces or due to your setup you are proxying a proxy.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thanks for the reply. `PersonDao` is extending another class called `GenericDao`. I am not getting `proxying a proxy`. I am using class-based proxies (@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass=true)) to avoid unnecessary interfaces. Do I need to make any changes in configuration ?

Comment: The fact that you use classbased proxies doesn't mean you cannot proxy a proxy... Also if it implements any interface it might break especially if a double proxy is getting created.

Comment: @M.Deinum - Thanks a lot for a suggestion. My GenericDao was implementing an interface. I removed it & tomcat started succesfully. But still I am getting same exception on `merge`

Comment: Post the code and new stacktrace.

Comment: @M.Deinum - I have replaced old stacktrace with new at top of question. And added PersonDao.java and GenericDao.java in **EDIT2** section. Thanks.

Comment: Don't create your own entitymanager. This basically renders the one from spring useless and you end up with 2 instances. Remove all references to the `EntityManagerFactory` in your `GenericDao`  and simply put a `@PersistenceContext` on the `EntityManager` field.

Comment: Another tip instead of rolling your own (or YAGD - Yet Another Generic Dao) `GenericDao` I would suggest taking a look at the [Spring Data JPA](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63855/discussion-between-hemu-and-m-deinum).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `EclipseLink and JOTM` running on `Tomcat` then in the persistence.xml, I guess you forgot the `property`:

```
    <properties>

        <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.jotm.JotmTransactionController"/>

    </properties>
```